# How to dynamically change colors of a PieChart in IReport Designer 5.6.0?

Tags: jasper-reports, pie-chart

I'm new with Jasper. I am using version: Jaspersoft IReport Designer 5.6.0
I'm working on a project developed by someone else.
I have a jrxml and I have no idea how to dynamically change the pieChart colors through a sql command.
I have my sql, with the field: "***cor_g***" => where the desired color is.
Inside the subDataset, I created my field:

```
<field name="cor_g" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

How do I insert that field dynamically inside this:

```
<seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#50B848"/>   ??
```

If I try like this:

```
<seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="cor_g"/>
```

Does not work.

chatGPT gave me solutions in java, but my Jasper version doesn't allow to use java. Only jar file, but I don't know how to associate it with my jrxml.
 Would anyone know how to resolve? 
Thank you very much in advance